# How to get/set value of MAX_ZONEORDER in user space?

Tags: linux, memory-management, configuration, linux-kernel

Is there any way to change `MAX_ZONEORDER` from user space without compiling kernel? How to get available nodes and pages on each node ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the value of max zoneorder in userspace using cat /proc/pagetypeinfo, but you cannot set max zoneorder value in userspace.
Value is set while memory subsystem ups, for setting value use kernel menuconfig.
default value is 11.